# I Only want to call MyFunction that contains Intent Method

Tags: android, android-intent, nullpointerexception, switch-statement

I have 8 Activity class. I created one more (9th class), to switch any of this 8 class. 9th class contains Intent Method. but when ı run as any of classes(1 or 2 or 3 or..) (not 9), app give a null pointer exception (Unfortunately! app has stopped.)

firstly, Class1 (Metot):

```
public void fonk2(){
    Intent i=null;
    Random r=new Random();
    int index=r.nextInt(4);

    switch(index){
        case 0:
            i=new Intent(Metot.this,Main6Activity.class);
            break;

        case 1:
            i=new Intent(Metot.this,Main7Activity.class);
            break;

        case 2:
            i=new Intent(Metot.this,Main8Activity.class);
            break;

        case 3:
            i=new Intent(Metot.this,Main9Activity.class);
            break;

    }
     startActivity(i);
```

in other classes, when ı click button, ı take an exception while programme running at line which function is called.

and Class2 (MainActivity2) :

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button b5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);

    b5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:{
                    Button view= (Button) v;

                    Metot m=new Metot();
                    m.fonk2();

                    view.getBackground().clearColorFilter();
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
                    Button view= (Button) v;
                    view.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x77000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                    view.invalidate();
                    break;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

I dealed with this problem all day. I researched but english is not my native language. ı found a few smilar example but these are not same problem. I only can't call MyFunction that contains Intent Method. Thanks.

Comment: Use Log class to Monitor and see where's your program stopped.

Comment: i=new Intent(Metot.this,Main7Activity.class);     this line..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Metot class is a subclass of Context, but it isn't attached to the application context since you create it with "new", to do what you want to do you have to create a class like this:

```
public class Metot {
    public static void fonk2(Activity activity){
        Intent i=null;
        Random r=new Random();
        int index=r.nextInt(4);

        switch(index){
            case 0:
                 i=new Intent(activity, Main6Activity.class);
            break;

            case 1:
                i=new Intent(activity, Main7Activity.class);
            break;

            ...
        }
        activity.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
Metot.fonk2(this);
```

Comment: well thanks. this problem has been solved. I needed to send activity class with parameter. I guess i need to a little more work on object-orianted logic.